# Items from last year not showing in SQL report builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services

I created a simple report which queries data from a SharePoint 2010 custom list, the list has 10 records, 5 created in 2010 and 5 created in 2011, when I run the report, which is pretty straight forward, I only see 5 results which are the records created in 2011.

I've looked for options and query filters and whatnot but I haven't found anything relating to the above problem.

No special filters have been applied.

Any idea's?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Erik, I have seen such behavior. The problem can be in your default view of SharePoint list - if it displays for example: only items created in 2011 report builder will only use them.


So my advice is to check your default view and if it's the source of problem - set view that displays all your items to be default.


Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add filter in Query Designer->In Applied filters Section like [image]